Responsive Design with Tailwind CSS Not Working on Web
I'm new to React Native and Expo, and I'm trying to use Tailwind CSS with twrnc for responsive design, targeting the web platform. Although the styling works, it is not responsive. I suspect there might be a misconfiguration somewhere.
Here are the details of my setup:
src/app/index.tsx
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text, Image } from 'react-native';
import tw from 'twrnc';
import { Link } from 'expo-router';

export default function Header () {

  return (
    <View style={tw`mb-2`}>

      <View style={tw`p-3 bg-white border-b`}>
        <View style={tw`items-center flex-wrap flex`}>

          <Link href='/' style={tw`flex-initial w-full lg:w-3/12 mb-1 items-center`}>
            <View>
              <Image source={require('@/assets/images/logo/logo-100.png')} style={[tw.style('w-65'), {width :'65px'}]} />
            </View>
            <View style={tw`flex-row text-h1`} id="project-name">
              <Text style={tw`text-xl font-bold text-red-600`}>Project Name</Text>
            </View>
          </Link>

          <View style={tw`w-full md:w-5/12 mb-1`}>
            <View style={tw`flex-row border rounded p-2`}>
              {/* content */}
            </View>
          </View>

          <View style={tw`flex w-full md:w-4/12 flex-row justify-around`}>
            {/* content */}
          </View>
        </View>
      </View>

    </View>
  );
};

Project Structure
project
├─ assets
│  ├─ fonts
│  └─ images
│     ├─ category
│     ├─ home
│     ├─ logo
│     │  ├─ favicon.ico
│     │  ├─ logo-100.png
│     └─ loader.gif
├─ src
│   ├─ app
│   │  ├─ +not-found.tsx
│   │  ├─ index.tsx
│   └─ style
│      └─ custom.css
├─ node_modules
├─ app.config.ts
├─ babel.config.js
├─ expo-env.d.ts
├─ global.d.ts
├─ index.ts
├─ metro.config.js
├─ package.json
├─ postcss.config.js
├─ styles.css
├─ tailwind.config.ts
├─ tsconfig.json
└─ yarn.lock

Configuration Files
app.config.ts
import type { ConfigContext, ExpoConfig } from "@expo/config";

export default ({ config }: ConfigContext): ExpoConfig => ({
  ...config,
  name: "project",
  slug: "project",
  version: "1.0.0",
  orientation: "portrait",
  icon: "./assets/images/logo/logo-100.png",
  scheme: "project",
  userInterfaceStyle: "automatic",
  splash: {
    image: "./assets/images/logo/logo-100.png",
    resizeMode: "contain",
    backgroundColor: "#ffffff",
  },
  ios: {
    supportsTablet: true,
    bundleIdentifier: "com.project.base",
  },
  android: {
    adaptiveIcon: {
      foregroundImage: "./assets/images/logo/logo-100.png",
      backgroundColor: "#ffffff",
    },
    package: "com.project.base",
  },
  web: {
    bundler: "metro",
    output: "single",
    favicon: "./assets/images/logo/logo-100.png",
  },
  plugins: [["expo-router"]],
  experiments: {
    typedRoutes: true,
  },
});

babel.config.js
module.exports = (api) => {
  api.cache(true);
  return {
    presets: [
      ["babel-preset-expo"]
    ],
    plugins: [
      "react-native-reanimated/plugin",
    ]
  };
};

index.ts
import "expo-router/entry";

metro.config.js
/** @type {import('expo/metro-config').MetroConfig} */

const { getDefaultConfig } = require('expo/metro-config');

module.exports = (async () => {
  const defaultConfig = await getDefaultConfig(__dirname, {
    isCSSEnabled: true,
  });

  return {
    ...defaultConfig,
    resolver: {
      ...defaultConfig.resolver,
      assetExts: defaultConfig.resolver.assetExts.filter(ext => ext !== 'svg'),
      sourceExts: [...defaultConfig.resolver.sourceExts, 'svg'],
    },
  };
})();

package.json
{
  "name": "project",
  "main": "index.ts",
  "version": "1.0.6",
  "homepage": "https://project.com",
  "license": "Apache-2.0",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "expo start --dev-client --clear",
    "dev:web": "expo start -c --web",
    "dev:android": "expo start -c --android",
    "android": "expo run:android",
    "ios": "expo run:ios",
    "web": "expo start -c --web",
    "export": "expo export -p web",
    "start": "expo start"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@expo/vector-icons": "^14.0.2",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "1.23.1",
    "@react-native-picker/picker": "^2.7.7",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.2",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.19",
    "babel-plugin-inline-import": "^3.0.0",
    "class-variance-authority": "^0.7.0",
    "clsx": "^2.1.0",
    "expo": "^51.0.0",
    "expo-linking": "~6.3.1",
    "expo-navigation-bar": "~3.0.4",
    "expo-router": "~3.5.14",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.27.4",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.12.1",
    "expo-system-ui": "~3.0.4",
    "postcss": "8.4.23",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "react-hook-form": "^7.51.4",
    "react-native": "0.74.1",
    "react-native-css-transformer": "^2.0.0",
    "react-native-event-listener": "^1.0.2",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.16.1",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~3.10.1",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.10.1",
    "react-native-screens": "3.31.1",
    "react-native-svg": "15.3.0",
    "react-native-web": "~0.19.6",
    "tailwind-merge": "^2.2.1",
    "tailwindcss": "3.4.4",
    "tailwindcss-animate": "^1.0.7",
    "twrnc": "^4.3.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.24.4",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.24.4",
    "@types/react": "18.2.0",
    "@types/sql.js": "^1.4.9",
    "drizzle-kit": "^0.21.2",
    "typescript": "^5.4.5"
  },
  "trustedDependencies": [
    "tailwindcss"
  ]
}

postcss.config.js
module.exports = {
  plugins: {
    tailwindcss: {},
    autoprefixer: {},
  },
};

styles.css
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

@layer base {
  :root {
    --background: 0 0% 100%;
    --foreground: 240 10% 3.9%;
    --card: 0 0% 100%;
    --card-foreground: 240 10% 3.9%;
    --popover: 0 0% 100%;
    --popover-foreground: 240 10% 3.9%;
    --primary: 240 5.9% 10%;
    --primary-foreground: 0 0% 98%;
    --secondary: 240 4.8% 95.9%;
    --secondary-foreground: 240 5.9% 10%;
    --muted: 240 4.8% 95.9%;
    --muted-foreground: 240 3.8% 46.1%;
    --accent: 240 4.8% 95.9%;
    --accent-foreground: 240 5.9% 10%;
    --destructive: 0 84.2% 60.2%;
    --destructive-foreground: 0 0% 98%;
    --border: 240 5.9% 90%;
    --input: 240 5.9% 90%;
    --ring: 240 5.9% 10%;
  }

  .dark:root {
    --background: 240 10% 3.9%;
    --foreground: 0 0% 98%;
    --card: 240 10% 3.9%;
    --card-foreground: 0 0% 98%;
    --popover: 240 10% 3.9%;
    --popover-foreground: 0 0% 98%;
    --primary: 0 0% 98%;
    --primary-foreground: 240 5.9% 10%;
    --secondary: 240 3.7% 15.9%;
    --secondary-foreground: 0 0% 98%;
    --muted: 240 3.7% 15.9%;
    --muted-foreground: 240 5% 64.9%;
    --accent: 240 3.7% 15.9%;
    --accent-foreground: 0 0% 98%;
    --destructive: 0 72% 51%;
    --destructive-foreground: 0 0% 98%;
    --border: 240 3.7% 15.9%;
    --input: 240 3.7% 15.9%;
    --ring: 240 4.9% 83.9%;
  }
}

tailwind.config.ts
module.exports = {
  darkMode: "class",
  content: [
    "./src/**/*.{ts,tsx,html,js,jsx}",
  ],
  presets: [],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}

tsconfig.json
{
  "extends": "expo/tsconfig.base",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "strict": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["src/*"],
      "@/assets/*": ["./assets/*"]
    }
  },
  "include": ["**/*.ts", "**/*.tsx", ".expo/types/**/*.ts", "expo-env.d.ts"]
}

